# Android - Moving a button with setTransationX()

Tags: android, button, translation

Pretty simple question :

Let's say we have a button named btnMove, which we want to move. In order to move it, I want to use setTranslationX and setTranslationY.

In order to do that, I wrote the following code :

```
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event){

            float currX,currY;
            int action = event.getAction();

            switch (action) {

                   case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
                        {
                         mPrevX = event.getRawX();
                         mPrevY = event.getRawY();     
                            break;
                        }

                   case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        {
                         currX = event.getRawX();
                         currY = event.getRawY();

                         btnMove.setTranslationX(currX - mPrevX);
                         btnMove.setTranslationY(currY - mPrevY);   
                            break;
                        }

                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: 
                            break;

                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            break;
                    }

                    return true;

            }
```

Pretty straightforward. My problem is that once we moved the button, if I am to move it again, it goes back to the starting position and then move following the drawn vector. Thing is I don't want it to go back before moving, I want it to move from where I dropped it !

I tried to look for things like fillAfter(true) but that seems to work only for animations.

Hope we'll figure this out soon :)

bRo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already tried setting the X of my button but I was getting something wrong. Clay, still with your technique, it gets it wrong because currX - mPrevX is the vector that the button follow, not the actual position. For example, if you just click your button, the vector is 0 and your button will be sent to the position 0. This is not what we want.

I was able to fix it by using by dropping the setTranslationX and only using setX(ButtonPreviousX + Vector), see below.

Thanks for the tip though

As we can see in my code, I dropped the setTranslationX altogether, can someone explain me why the setTranslationX was getting it wrong?

This is my final code that works :

```
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event){

             float currX,currY;

                int action = event.getAction();
                switch (action ) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                        mPrevX = event.getRawX();
                        mPrevY = event.getRawY();

                        btnPrevX = btnMove.getX();
                        btnPrevY = btnMove.getY();

                        break;
                    }

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    {   
                            currX = event.getRawX();
                            currY = event.getRawY();

                            btnMove.setX(btnPrevX + currX - mPrevX);
                            btnMove.setY(btnPrevY + currY - mPrevY);

                        break;
                    }



                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        break;
                }

                return true;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

After translating the button, you need to set its position to where it ends up.

So, after you translate it, do this...

```
yourButton.setX(currX - mPrevX);
yourButton.setY(currY - mPrevY);
```

Your problem is that the buttons position is not changing after you translate it, so when you translate it again, it's from the original position.